# Automapper help mapping a complex c# objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map from `Vehicle` object to the `Motor` object using `Automapper`

```
public class Range<T>
{
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }
}

public Enum SpeedType
{
    [Display(Name = "-")] Unknown = 0,
    [Display(Name = "M")] Manual= 1,
    [Display(Name = "A")] Automatic= 2
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Range<string> Speed { get; set; }
}

public class Motor
{
    public Range<SpeedType?> Speed { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using the `MapFrom` (reading the documentation) without any success. Can someone point me in the right direction. I am not even sure if this can be even mapped using `Automapper`. I have used automapper in the past for simple mappings.

Comment: Using `Range<T>` with an Enum as you've set it doesn't make sense.  Why is Automatic *max* and Manual *min* or the other way around,  There is no concept in the real world of one being greater than the other.

Comment: I have simplified the example
Suppose for vehicle Min ="M", Max="A" then I want to convert it to Min=1,Max=2

Comment: To be frank I'm not a big fan of `AutoMapper`. I had to use it in a project for more than a year but actually it is only good for making simple things more complicated than necessary. Some `FromDto` and `ToDto` [extension] methods are just simpler, faster, easier to debug and more reactive to code changes. Mapping between different class layouts often results practically as much code (or even more with tons of lambdas) as simply writing the mapping manually. See also: https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<string, SpeedType?>().ConvertUsing(speed =>
    {
        switch (speed)
        {
            case "M": return SpeedType.Manual;
            case "A": return SpeedType.Automatic;
            default: return SpeedType.Unknown;
        }
    });

    cfg.CreateMap<Range<string>, Range<SpeedType?>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Vehicle, Motor>();
});

var vehicle = new Vehicle
{
    Speed = new Range<string>
    {
        Min = "M",
        Max = "A"
    }
};

var motor = Mapper.Map<Vehicle, Motor>(vehicle);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Learned that switch could be added to Automapper.

Comment: FYI, you can basically add anything you want inside the curly braces. This is a lambda expression, so any code is valid as long as all the code path returns something

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following mapping to solve my problem.  I wrote a GetEnum custom method

```
CreateMap<Vehicle,Motor>()
.ForMember(g => g.Speed, opt => opt.MapFrom(u=> new Range<SpeedType?>
                {
                    Min = EnumHelper.GetEnum<SpeedType?>(u.Speed.Min),
                    Max = EnumHelper.GetEnum<SpeedType?>(u.Speed.Max),
                }))
```